# Difference between Bucket level lock and segment level lock in ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, concurrency

I gone through below link and some online video tutorials but am unable to find exact differnece between Bucket level lock and segment level lock in ConcurrentHashMap.

[ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 `ConcurrentHashMap` changed its logic to use bucket level locks instead of segment level locks.

**What is the difference?**

In Java 7 the map was subdivided among Segments, each of which itself is a concurrently readable hash table. Each segment contains some number of buckets inside.

The bucket itself is a list/array of key-value pairs.

The number of threads working with map in parallel was limited to the number of segments.

In Java 8 lock level was moved to a bucket level, while segments were removed (it is still in the code, but without use).

So, basically, in Java 7 inserting was locking a few buckets, in Java 8 - only one.

Another reason why it was done is that the number of threads, which are working in parallel with the map, can increase during map size increasing (more buckets - more threads). In Java 7 segments size was fixed, and it couldn't be changed without recreating a map.

Comment: you mean bucket level or segment level lock depends concurrency level which we can specify (default is 16)

Comment: No, that's two different approaches to make map safe to parallel changes. Concurrency level is only a part of it.

Comment: Why cannot find the bucket level lock information on Java 8 doc?